# Trying to fix a module not found error in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[An error in REACT displaying a MODULE NOT FOUND ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSjVx.png)

How this error started was, that I was trying to add a background image with a tailwind CSS and suddenly got this error and later commented on the code and still displaying the same error. tried all possible ways that I can think of still not working.. would like to hear from the community.

Answer (score 1):

I think you put images in public folder of reactJs structure. If that is true then you wrongly call the image just use

```
<img src="./images/bg-card-front.png" alt="just an image">
```

Hope you like my answer, if you found any issue just lemme know.

Comment: You can also import the image inside your component `import myImage from './images/img.jpg'`

Comment: Thanks, but I have also tried commenting on the line of code  but still displaying the same error

Comment: @peter can you able to share you code on any platform if possible. Lemme check the error.